# Could not execute shell 'on K8S pods

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubectl, rancher

Use Rancher-2.6.6 install K8S(v1.23.7+rke2r2), the related issue is [here](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/39635).

I could not execute shell on any container in K8S(v1.23.7+rke2r2).

The log is a little tediously long, do not know it could be help or not.

I am not familiar with GO, It takes me few hours and have no idea how to resolve it. Any help will be very pleasure.

```
[root@123 ~]# /var/lib/rancher/rke2/bin/kubectl --kubeconfig rke2.yaml -n minio  --v=9 exec --stdin --tty console-656df75d45-bdb4m -- /bin/bash
I1117 17:59:25.557423 1522170 loader.go:372] Config loaded from file:  rke2.yaml
I1117 17:59:25.814339 1522170 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.23.7+rke2r2 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/42c05a5" 'https://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/namespaces/minio/pods/console-656df75d45-bdb4m'
I1117 17:59:25.814906 1522170 round_trippers.go:510] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:127.0.0.1:6443 succeed
I1117 17:59:25.824624 1522170 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 0 ms Dial 0 ms TLSHandshake 3 ms ServerProcessing 5 ms Duration 10 ms
I1117 17:59:25.824713 1522170 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
I1117 17:59:25.824735 1522170 round_trippers.go:580]     Date: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 09:59:25 GMT
I1117 17:59:25.824808 1522170 round_trippers.go:580]     Audit-Id: 06174be1-bd2f-4500-a59b-58bf68ff79f9
I1117 17:59:25.824832 1522170 round_trippers.go:580]     Cache-Control: no-cache, private
I1117 17:59:25.824884 1522170 round_trippers.go:580]     Content-Type: application/json
I1117 17:59:25.824909 1522170 round_trippers.go:580]     X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid: fb6d6698-bf27-4014-9f5c-9d7405a8ecc9
I1117 17:59:25.824927 1522170 round_trippers.go:580]     X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid: 95a48fbf-d3d7-44a2-aa35-f6b4ccc22845
I1117 17:59:25.825269 1522170 request.go:1181] Response Body: {"kind":"Pod","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"name":"console-656df75d45-bdb4m","generateName":"console-656df75d45-","namespace":"minio","uid":"aa46973d-debc-419d-8d52-338bba5e121f","resourceVersion":"61701433","creationTimestamp":"2022-11-17T06:07:05Z","labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"minio-operator-console","app.kubernetes.io/name":"operator","pod-template-hash":"656df75d45"},"annotations":{"cni.projectcalico.org/containerID":"6b52546c61cebbc4450c21e7bedaa1198aa176ee708cfa416dd570717e89d14d","cni.projectcalico.org/podIP":"10.42.48.137/32","cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs":"10.42.48.137/32","kubernetes.io/psp":"global-unrestricted-psp"},"ownerReferences":[{"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"ReplicaSet","name":"console-656df75d45","uid":"5954db5d-1892-41af-82c9-8aad46116e48","controller":true,"blockOwnerDeletion":true}],"managedFields":[{"manager":"Go-http-client","operation":"Update","apiVersion":"v1","time":"2022-11-17T06:07:05Z","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:metadata":{"f:annotations":{"f:cni.projectcalico.org/containerID":{},"f:cni.projectcalico.org/podIP":{},"f:cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs":{}}}},"subresource":"status"},{"manager":"kube-controller-manager","operation":"Update","apiVersion":"v1","time":"2022-11-17T06:07:05Z","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:metadata":{"f:generateName":{},"f:labels":{".":{},"f:app.kubernetes.io/instance":{},"f:app.kubernetes.io/name":{},"f:pod-template-hash":{}},"f:ownerReferences":{".":{},"k:{\"uid\":\"5954db5d-1892-41af-82c9-8aad46116e48\"}":{}}},"f:spec":{"f:containers":{"k:{\"name\":\"operator\"}":{".":{},"f:args":{},"f:env":{".":{},"k:{\"name\":\"CONSOLE_OPERATOR_MODE\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:value":{}}},"f:image":{},"f:imagePullPolicy":{},"f:name":{},"f:ports":{".":{},"k:{\"containerPort\":9090,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:containerPort":{},"f:name":{},"f:protocol":{}},"k:{\"containerPort\":9443,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:containerPort":{},"f:name":{},"f:protocol":{}}},"f:resources":{},"f:terminationMessagePath":{},"f:terminationMessagePolicy":{}}},"f:dnsPolicy":{},"f:enableServiceLinks":{},"f:restartPolicy":{},"f:schedulerName":{},"f:securityContext":{".":{},"f:runAsNonRoot":{},"f:runAsUser":{}},"f:serviceAccount":{},"f:serviceAccountName":{},"f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds":{}}}},{"manager":"kubelet","operation":"Update","apiVersion":"v1","time":"2022-11-17T06:07:14Z","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:status":{"f:conditions":{"k:{\"type\":\"ContainersReady\"}":{".":{},"f:lastProbeTime":{},"f:lastTransitionTime":{},"f:status":{},"f:type":{}},"k:{\"type\":\"Initialized\"}":{".":{},"f:lastProbeTime":{},"f:lastTransitionTime":{},"f:status":{},"f:type":{}},"k:{\"type\":\"Ready\"}":{".":{},"f:lastProbeTime":{},"f:lastTransitionTime":{},"f:status":{},"f:type":{}}},"f:containerStatuses":{},"f:hostIP":{},"f:phase":{},"f:podIP":{},"f:podIPs":{".":{},"k:{\"ip\":\"10.42.48.137\"}":{".":{},"f:ip":{}}},"f:startTime":{}}},"subresource":"status"}]},"spec":{"volumes":[{"name":"kube-api-access-qb55d","projected":{"sources":[{"serviceAccountToken":{"expirationSeconds":3607,"path":"token"}},{"configMap":{"name":"kube-root-ca.crt","items":[{"key":"ca.crt","path":"ca.crt"}]}},{"downwardAPI":{"items":[{"path":"namespace","fieldRef":{"apiVersion":"v1","fieldPath":"metadata.namespace"}}]}}],"defaultMode":420}}],"containers":[{"name":"operator","image":"mirrorhub.swdcmg.com/minio/console:v0.21.3","args":["server"],"ports":[{"name":"http","containerPort":9090,"protocol":"TCP"},{"name":"https","containerPort":9443,"protocol":"TCP"}],"env":[{"name":"CONSOLE_OPERATOR_MODE","value":"on"}],"resources":{},"volumeMounts":[{"name":"kube-api-access-qb55d","readOnly":true,"mountPath":"/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount"}],"terminationMessagePath":"/dev/termination-log","terminationMessagePolicy":"File","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent"}],"restartPolicy":"Always","terminationGracePeriodSeconds":30,"dnsPolicy":"ClusterFirst","serviceAccountName":"console-sa","serviceAccount":"console-sa","nodeName":"123.hdp.dc.xyz","securityContext":{"runAsUser":1000,"runAsNonRoot":true},"schedulerName":"default-scheduler","tolerations":[{"key":"node.kubernetes.io/not-ready","operator":"Exists","effect":"NoExecute","tolerationSeconds":300},{"key":"node.kubernetes.io/unreachable","operator":"Exists","effect":"NoExecute","tolerationSeconds":300}],"priority":0,"enableServiceLinks":true,"preemptionPolicy":"PreemptLowerPriority"},"status":{"phase":"Running","conditions":[{"type":"Initialized","status":"True","lastProbeTime":null,"lastTransitionTime":"2022-11-17T06:07:05Z"},{"type":"Ready","status":"True","lastProbeTime":null,"lastTransitionTime":"2022-11-17T06:07:14Z"},{"type":"ContainersReady","status":"True","lastProbeTime":null,"lastTransitionTime":"2022-11-17T06:07:14Z"},{"type":"PodScheduled","status":"True","lastProbeTime":null,"lastTransitionTime":"2022-11-17T06:07:05Z"}],"hostIP":"10.0.1.38","podIP":"10.42.48.137","podIPs":[{"ip":"10.42.48.137"}],"startTime":"2022-11-17T06:07:05Z","containerStatuses":[{"name":"operator","state":{"running":{"startedAt":"2022-11-17T06:07:13Z"}},"lastState":{},"ready":true,"restartCount":0,"image":"mirrorhub.swdcmg.com/minio/console:v0.21.3","imageID":"mirrorhub.swdcmg.com/minio/console@sha256:c6d591a56c1592516b9814b930f6a466395093db64032cc1232e0e97d9b330cf","containerID":"containerd://c01cdf6b493bc85d9948c8e1330743b94640cd5fa9fb01c65423fbb50ea9e420","started":true}],"qosClass":"BestEffort"}}
I1117 17:59:25.830130 1522170 podcmd.go:88] Defaulting container name to operator
I1117 17:59:25.830901 1522170 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XPOST  -H "X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v4.channel.k8s.io" -H "X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v3.channel.k8s.io" -H "X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v2.channel.k8s.io" -H "X-Stream-Protocol-Version: channel.k8s.io" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.23.7+rke2r2 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/42c05a5" 'https://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/namespaces/minio/pods/console-656df75d45-bdb4m/exec?command=%2Fbin%2Fbash&container=operator&stdin=true&stdout=true&tty=true'
                                                                 I1117 17:59:25.861715 1522170 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 0 ms Dial 0 ms TLSHandshake 0 ms Duration 30 ms
                                                                                                                                                                                                I1117 17:59:25.861770 1522170 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
                                               I1117 17:59:25.861788 1522170 round_trippers.go:580]     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
                                                                                                                                       I1117 17:59:25.861802 1522170 round_trippers.go:580]     Content-Length: 42
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  I1117 17:59:25.861815 1522170 round_trippers.go:580]     Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
                                                                                           I1117 17:59:25.861833 1522170 round_trippers.go:580]     Date: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 09:59:25 GMT
                                                                                                                                                                                       I1117 17:59:25.862631 1522170 helpers.go:219] server response object: [{
  "metadata": {}
}]
F1117 17:59:25.862770 1522170 helpers.go:118] Error from server:
goroutine 1 [running]:
k8s.io/klog/v2.stacks(0x1)
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:1038 +0x8a
k8s.io/klog/v2.(*loggingT).output(0x331bd40, 0x3, 0x0, 0xc0001ced90, 0x2, {0x27bb393, 0x10}, 0xc000430800, 0x0)
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:987 +0x5fd
k8s.io/klog/v2.(*loggingT).printDepth(0xc0005a4318, 0x13, 0x0, {0x0, 0x0}, 0x0, {0xc00042d2c0, 0x1, 0x1})
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:735 +0x1ae
k8s.io/klog/v2.FatalDepth(...)
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:1518
k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util.fatal({0xc0005a4318, 0x13}, 0xc00049d220)
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util/helpers.go:96 +0xc5
k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util.checkErr({0x22b7c60, 0xc00049d220}, 0x212ec10)
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util/helpers.go:191 +0x7d7
k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util.CheckErr(...)
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/util/helpers.go:118
k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/exec.NewCmdExec.func1(0xc000628c80, {0xc0009ece60, 0x2, 0xa})
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/exec/exec.go:97 +0xc5
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0xc000628c80, {0xc0009ecd20, 0xa, 0xa})
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:860 +0x5f8
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0xc0007dfb80)
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:974 +0x3bc
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:902
k8s.io/component-base/cli.run(0xc0007dfb80)
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/component-base/cli/run.go:146 +0x325
k8s.io/component-base/cli.RunNoErrOutput(...)
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/component-base/cli/run.go:84
main.main()
        cmd/kubectl/kubectl.go:30 +0x1e

goroutine 6 [chan receive]:
k8s.io/klog/v2.(*loggingT).flushDaemon(0x0)
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:1181 +0x6a
created by k8s.io/klog/v2.init.0
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/klog/v2/klog.go:420 +0xfb

goroutine 35 [select]:
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil(0x0, {0x22b7f60, 0xc000598000}, 0x1, 0xc0000fe360)
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:167 +0x13b
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil(0x0, 0x12a05f200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:133 +0x89
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.Until(...)
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:90
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.Forever(0x0, 0x0)
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:81 +0x28
created by k8s.io/component-base/logs.InitLogs
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/component-base/logs/logs.go:179 +0x85

goroutine 25 [IO wait]:
internal/poll.runtime_pollWait(0x7f2601536858, 0x72)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:303 +0x85
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).wait(0xc000151f00, 0xc000800000, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:84 +0x32
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).waitRead(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:89
internal/poll.(*FD).Read(0xc000151f00, {0xc000800000, 0x2172, 0x2172})
        /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:167 +0x25a
net.(*netFD).Read(0xc000151f00, {0xc000800000, 0xc000801578, 0x1a})
        /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_posix.go:56 +0x29
net.(*conn).Read(0xc00011c0f8, {0xc000800000, 0x51399e, 0xc00055f7f0})
        /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:183 +0x45
crypto/tls.(*atLeastReader).Read(0xc0004905d0, {0xc000800000, 0x0, 0x40c2ed})
        /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:777 +0x3d
bytes.(*Buffer).ReadFrom(0xc0006033f8, {0x22b5dc0, 0xc0004905d0})
        /usr/local/go/src/bytes/buffer.go:204 +0x98
crypto/tls.(*Conn).readFromUntil(0xc000603180, {0x22b9220, 0xc00011c0f8}, 0xbff)
        /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:799 +0xe5
crypto/tls.(*Conn).readRecordOrCCS(0xc000603180, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:606 +0x112
crypto/tls.(*Conn).readRecord(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:574
crypto/tls.(*Conn).Read(0xc000603180, {0xc000231000, 0x1000, 0x9592c0})
        /usr/local/go/src/crypto/tls/conn.go:1277 +0x16f
bufio.(*Reader).Read(0xc0003e1da0, {0xc00021c820, 0x9, 0x967862})
        /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:227 +0x1b4
io.ReadAtLeast({0x22b5ba0, 0xc0003e1da0}, {0xc00021c820, 0x9, 0x9}, 0x9)
        /usr/local/go/src/io/io.go:328 +0x9a
io.ReadFull(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/io/io.go:347
golang.org/x/net/http2.readFrameHeader({0xc00021c820, 0x9, 0xc0016df5f0}, {0x22b5ba0, 0xc0003e1da0})
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/golang.org/x/net/http2/frame.go:237 +0x6e
golang.org/x/net/http2.(*Framer).ReadFrame(0xc00021c7e0)
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/golang.org/x/net/http2/frame.go:498 +0x95
golang.org/x/net/http2.(*clientConnReadLoop).run(0xc00055ff98)
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/golang.org/x/net/http2/transport.go:2101 +0x130
golang.org/x/net/http2.(*ClientConn).readLoop(0xc00004e900)
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/golang.org/x/net/http2/transport.go:1997 +0x6f
created by golang.org/x/net/http2.(*Transport).newClientConn
        /go/src/kubernetes/vendor/golang.org/x/net/http2/transport.go:725 +0xac5

goroutine 27 [syscall]:
os/signal.signal_recv()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sigqueue.go:169 +0x98
os/signal.loop()
        /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:24 +0x19
created by os/signal.Notify.func1.1
        /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal.go:151 +0x2c
```

Comment: Some related issue: https://forums.rancher.com/t/kubectl-exec-log-get-error-from-server/36852/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. We deployed an app used 10010. We change the 10010. It is all good now.